# google url shortener api with wp_remote_post

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, curl

I try to make google url shortener with wp_remote_post()

but I got error result,

I know how to use CURL, but CURL not allowed in WordPress!

---

This resource for API with WordPress:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_retrieve_body

http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API#Other_Arguments

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post#Related

---

This google url shortener API docs:

https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#shorten

---

This is my code:

```
function google_url_shrt{
    $url = 'http://example-long-url.com/example-long-url'; // long url to short it
    $args = array(
            "headers"   =>  array( "Content-type:application/json" ),
            "body"      =>  array( "longUrl" => $url )
        );

    $short = wp_remote_post("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url", $args);
    $retrieve = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $short );
    $response = json_decode($retrieve, true);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($response);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WordPress API requires that the `headers` array contain an element `content-type` if you want to change the content type of a POST request.

Also, it looks like the `body` of your HTTP request is being passed as a PHP array, not as a JSON string as the Google Shortener API requires.

Wrap the array definition for `body` in a [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) statement, and make the `headers` field a sub-array, and give it a shot:

```
$args = array(
    'headers' =>  array('content-type' => 'application/json'),
    'body'    =>  json_encode(array('longUrl' => $url)),
);
```

Alternative, you could just write the JSON format yourself as it is fairly simple:

```
$args = array(
    'headers' =>  array('content-type' => 'application/json'),
    'body'    =>  '{"longUrl":"' .  $url . '"}',
);
```

Comment: i will try and i will tell you, wait me.

Comment: not working!
look to this messsage:
This API does not support parsing form-encoded input.

Comment: The format of your `headers` variable was also wrong according to the WordPress documentation.  I updated my answer - try it again.